# Arcobjects not drawing GraphicContainer if layers are in the TOC

Tags: arcobjects, c#

Im trying to draw some graphic labels in Layout View for every row in a feature class chosen by a user in a combobox. I am just in testing out some code to draw the label graphic and it works fine, but as soon as I add layers to my TOC and try to click a button to generate the graphic it does not work and does not draw. Is there something I am missing?

```
        IMxDocument pMxDoc = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;
        IActiveView activeView = pMxDoc.ActiveView as IActiveView;
        ITextElement pTextElement;
        IElement pElement;
        ICallout pCallout;
        IFormattedTextSymbol pTextSymbol;
        IGraphicsContainer pGraphicsContainer;
        IPoint anchorPoint = new PointClass();
        anchorPoint.PutCoords(50, 50);
        pTextElement = new TextElementClass();
        pElement = pTextElement as IElement;
        pTextElement.Text = "<UND><BOL>As-Cleared</BOL></UND>" + "\r\n" + " 3.20ha" + "\r\n" + "Partial Cleared";

        ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IScreenDisplay screenDisplay = activeView.ScreenDisplay;
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IDisplayTransformation displayTransformation = screenDisplay.DisplayTransformation;

        int x, y;
        displayTransformation.FromMapPoint(anchorPoint, out x, out y);
        IPoint messagePoint = displayTransformation.ToMapPoint(x + 120, y - 180);
        pElement.Geometry = messagePoint;

        pTextSymbol = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.TextSymbol();
        pCallout = new BalloonCallout();
        pTextSymbol.Background = pCallout as ITextBackground;
        pCallout.AnchorPoint = anchorPoint;
        pTextElement.Symbol = pTextSymbol;

        pGraphicsContainer = activeView as IGraphicsContainer;
        pGraphicsContainer.AddElement(pElement, 0);
        pElement.Activate(activeView.ScreenDisplay);
        activeView.PartialRefresh(esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGraphics, pElement, null);
```

Comment: what happens if you comment out pElement.Activate?

Comment: Unfortunately the same thing. If I open my app and click generate before any layers are added to the TOC it will generate the balloon call out. if i add any layers to the TOC even if I remove them after it will not draw the graphic. EDIT: Actually now that I look it seems to be drawing it just in a completely different location vs when no layers are added. Any ideas why this may be?